# Using cumsum by columns

Tags: r

I have a matrix, for example:

```
A= [ 1 2 3 4
     3 5 6 6
     4 1 2 3 ]
```

I want to get the cumulative sum of the columns in the form of another matrix (or data frame). For example, this matrix would give:

```
B= [1 2 3 4
    4 7 9 10
    8 8 8 13]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If `A` is a matrix, use `apply`:

```
A <- structure(c(1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 3, 6, 2, 4, 6, 3), .Dim = 3:4)
B <- apply(A, 2, cumsum)
B
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4
# [2,]    4    7    9   10
# [3,]    8    8   11   13
```

If `A` is a data.frame, use `lapply`:

```
B <- as.data.frame(A)
B[] <- lapply(B, cumsum)
B
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1  1  2  3  4
# 2  4  7  9 10
# 3  8  8 11 13
```

Answer (score 0):

> Using `dplyr` for data frames:

```
library(dplyr)    
m <- matrix(c(1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 3, 6, 2, 4, 6, 3), 3, 4)
as.data.frame(m) %>% mutate_each(funs(cumsum))
```

> With `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
df <- as.data.frame(m)
sqldf('SELECT SUM(b.V1) V1, SUM(b.V2) V2, SUM(b.V3) V3, SUM(b.V4) V4
      FROM df AS a, df AS b WHERE b.rowid <= a.rowid 
      GROUP BY a.V1 ORDER BY a.rowid')
```

Output:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  1  2  3  4
2  4  7  9 10
3  8  8 11 13
```